# Index layout: on the same line when only one subitem

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, idxlayout

I am making an index for my document using `\makeindex`.
And in my document I have subindex entries like :

```
\index{word1!subword11}
\index{word1!subword12}
```

But when there is only one subentry in the whole document associated to a given word, I would like to know how to do as if there was no subentry. In other terms, if the only sub-entry of `word2` is `subword21` in the whole document, I want the result to be equal to : `\index{word2!subword21} == \index{word2 subword21}`.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to achieve this with the standard `makeindex`/`xindy` approach and, given that this question has been unanswered for so long, it seems that no one else can think of a way. So here's an alternative method that uses a completely different approach. Instead of using `\index`, this uses the [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) interface with [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) and [`bib2gls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls).

All terms need to first be defined in one or more `.bib` files. For example, `entries.bib`:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@index{test}

@index{samplephrase,
  name = {sample phrase}
}

@index{word1}

@index{subword11,
  name={subword11},
  parent={word1}
}

@index{subword12,
  name={subword12},
  parent={word1}
}

@index{word2}

@index{subword21,
  name={subword21},
  parent={word2}
}

@index{subword22,
  name={subword22},
  parent={word2}
}
```

The first MWE uses the default settings, which results in a lonely sub-item, for comparison:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[record, % use bib2gls
 nostyles,% don't load default styles
 stylemods={bookindex},% load glossary-bookindex.sty
 style=bookindex % set style
]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={entries}, % data in entries.bib
  sort={en}% sort according to this language tag (en = English)
]

\begin{document}
\Gls{test}, \gls{samplephrase}, \gls{subword11}, \gls{subword12} and 
\gls{subword21}.

\printunsrtglossary[title=Index]
\end{document}
```

If the document is called `test.tex` then the document build is:

```
pdflatex test
bib2gls -g test
pdflatex test
```

(Replace `pdflatex` with `xelatex` etc, as appropriate.)

The result is:

[image: Test, sample phrase, subword11, subword12 and subword21. Index S sample phrase, 1 T test, 1 W word1 subword11, 1 subword12, 1 word2 subword21, 1]

The lonely sub-item can be shifted up a hierarchical level with the `flatten-lonely` option. The value must be one of `false` (don't modify), `presort` (which adjusts the hierarchical level before sorting) or `postsort` (which adjusts after sorting).

`flatten-lonely=presort` will move the item since it will be sorted by its name rather than following its parent's position:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[record, % use bib2gls
 nostyles,% don't load default styles
 stylemods={bookindex},% load glossary-bookindex.sty
 style=bookindex % set style
]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={entries}, % data in entries.bib
  sort={en},% sort according to this language tag (en = English)
  flatten-lonely=presort% flatten lonely sub-items
]

\begin{document}
\Gls{test}, \gls{samplephrase}, \gls{subword11}, \gls{subword12} and 
\gls{subword21}.

\printunsrtglossary[title=Index]
\end{document}
```

[image: Test, sample phrase, subword11, subword12 and subword21. Index S sample phrase, 1 subword21, 1 T test, 1 W word1 subword11, 1 subword12, 1]

The sub-item has moved to the S letter group and its parent (word2) has been removed completely.

`flatten-lonely=postsort` makes the adjustments after sorting so the sub-item is moved up a hierarchical level but stays in the same relative position. The name is adjusted and the parent item is removed:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[record, % use bib2gls
 nostyles,% don't load default styles
 stylemods={bookindex},% load glossary-bookindex.sty
 style=bookindex % set style
]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={entries}, % data in entries.bib
  sort={en},% sort according to this language tag (en = English)
  flatten-lonely=postsort% flatten lonely sub-items
]

\begin{document}
\Gls{test}, \gls{samplephrase}, \gls{subword11}, \gls{subword12} and 
\gls{subword21}.

\printunsrtglossary[title=Index]
\end{document}
```

[image: Test, sample phrase, subword11, subword12 and subword21. Index S sample phrase, 1 T test, 1 W word1 subword11, 1 subword12, 1 word2, subword21, 1]

The text used by `\gls{subword21}` hasn't changed, but the entry is now listed as "word2, subword21". The `name` field is actually changed to:

```
\bibglsflattenedchildpostsort{word2}{subword21}
```

which is simply defined as

```
\providecommand*{\bibglsflattenedchildpostsort}[2]{#1, #2}
```

in the `.glstex` file that's input by `\GlsXtrLoadResources`, so you can modify the formatting. For example:

```
\newcommand*{\bibglsflattenedchildpostsort}[2]{#1 #2}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={entries}, % data in entries.bib
  sort={en},% sort according to this language tag (en = English)
  flatten-lonely=postsort,% flatten lonely sub-items
]
```

By default, you can't flatten a lonely sub-item if its parent has been indexed. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[record, % use bib2gls
 nostyles,% don't load default styles
 stylemods={bookindex},% load glossary-bookindex.sty
 style=bookindex % set style
]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={entries}, % data in entries.bib
  sort={en},% sort according to this language tag (en = English)
  flatten-lonely=postsort% flatten lonely sub-items
]

\begin{document}
\Gls{test}, \gls{samplephrase}, \gls{word1}, \gls{subword12} and
\gls{subword21}.

\printunsrtglossary[title=Index]
\end{document}
```

There are now two lonely sub-items, but only one is adjusted because the other has a parent that's been indexed:

[image: Test, sample phrase, word1, subword12 and subword21. Index S sample phrase, 1 T test, 1 W word1 1 subword12, 1 word2, subword21, 1]

In this case, setting `flatten-lonely-rule={discard unrecorded}` can adjust the lonely sub-items but will only remove unindexed parents:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[record, % use bib2gls
 nostyles,% don't load default styles
 stylemods={bookindex},% load glossary-bookindex.sty
 style=bookindex % set style
]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={entries}, % data in entries.bib
  sort={en},% sort according to this language tag (en = English)
  flatten-lonely=postsort,% flatten lonely sub-items
  flatten-lonely-rule={discard unrecorded}
]

\begin{document}
\Gls{test}, \gls{samplephrase}, \gls{word1}, \gls{subword12} and
\gls{subword21}.

\printunsrtglossary[title=Index]
\end{document}
```

The result is now:

[image: Test, sample phrase, word1, subword12 and subword21. Index S sample phrase, 1 T test, 1 W word1 1 word1, subword12, 1 word2, subword21, 1]